# Can't Move to End of Line With Vim on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I'm using Vim on Cygwin. Basically, Vim won't allow me to move past the last character on a line when I'm in normal/command mode. It will let me move right before the last character but not after it. Any thoughts on what might be wrong?

Comment: If you have a line containing the single word `foobar` and you hit on the `$` key, does your cursor land on the `r` character ? (meaning if you hit `x` you get `fooba`) If you want your cursor to move past the last character on the line, you could try the following command: `:set virtualedit+=onemore`

Comment: @saginaw Yeh if I hit x I do get fooba. But if I hit the $ key nothing happens

Comment: @saginaw Thanks that solved it. Would you mind explaining what that did and why that was not the default setting?

Comment: Vim's cursor is always _on_ a character position, never _between_ character positions, even though some cursor shapes make it appear that the cursor is between character positions. When your cursor appears to be before the last character, it is probably _on_ the last character. That is Vim's normal behavior. You can change it, if you like, by following saginaw's suggestion.

Comment: @garyjohn I see, the cursor is displayed differently in the Cygwin Vim than in the raw Linux Vim. Thanks.

Comment: @Joel The `$` key should move your cursor on the last character on the line, which in the case of `foobar` is `r`. So after hitting `$`, on my machine, I have a white blinking cursor on the `r` character, which means that the next operator (`x` for example) will affect `r`. If you have the same behavior on your machine, I think it's the default and normal one. If something different happens, I'm sorry but I don't know why.

Comment: @Joel For the last command I mentioned, I found it after searching on the web. Here's the link from which I copied it: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Why-doesn-t-the-cursor-go-beyond-the-last-character-in-Vim-when-in-command-mode-td3399472.html

Comment: @saginaw Since I am using Vim on Cygwin, my cursor is in between the characters, rather than on a character for some reason. Therefore it ends up before the last character rather than on it. Your fixed solved the problem though. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Vim's cursor is always *on* a character position, never *between* character positions, even though some cursor shapes make it appear that the cursor is between character positions. When your cursor appears to be before the last character, it is probably *on* the last character. That is Vim's normal behavior. You can change it, if you like, by following saginaw's suggestion of using the command

```
:set virtualedit+=onemore
```